# What is the best way to create an Html Table out of a sharepoint list in a Web Part?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I want to create a deployable .wsp Web Part and I want to fetch a Custom List and show it in an Html Table inside that web part.

I know how to create a .wsp web part, and I can also create the table overriding the `RenderContents` or `CreateChildControls` methods of WebPart class.

But I want to know the easy and best method for outputting an Html Table in a WebPart.

Should I use a UserControl so that, I can add any Asp.Net controls inside it and then load it in the Web Part ??

Please tell me any solutions ?

Comment: Don't the native webparts do that ? What are problems you encountered and why did you choose a custom webpart ?

Comment: I need to add some custom columns dynamically, and also this is an assignment for me as I am going through Sharepoint Training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puneet i would recommend using Data View webparts which uses xslt to customize the view in which a list data is rendered. 
You can take help of SharePoint Desginer to add a Data View Web Part.

http://www.lcbridge.nl/vision/2009/dvwp.htm

Comment: But, I want to make the new web part deployable as a feature just to show the use of Solution Package. If I will use DVWP, then is it not already present in the web parts gallery ? How will I create a new customized web part out of it, add one more column and then deploy it as a WSP package ?

Comment: although exporting the dwp file is an option but i would suggest to create a custom webpart and bind the data spgrid view

Answer (score 1):

Check out this video. It shows how to build a Visual Web Part (one that uses a user control for UI) in Visual Studio 2008 and shows how to bind data from a list to a GridView control.

http://www.vimeo.com/11285888